# Get Data for two dates in one row

Tags: sql, oracle, date, analytics

Please consider the following data-set.

| Account No | Month End Date | Balance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123960 | 31-Dec-2021 | 1000 |
| 123960 | 31-Jan-2022 | 1500 |
| 123960 | 28-Feb-2022 | 1700 |
| 123960 | 31-Mar-2022 | 2100 |
| 123960 | 30-Apr-2022 | 1900 |

Can you please advise me the best possible way to get the following output to compare one month with the previous one.

| Account No | Month End Date | Balance | Previous Month Balance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123960 | 31-Dec-2021 | 1000 | - |
| 123960 | 31-Jan-2022 | 1500 | 1000 |
| 123960 | 28-Feb-2022 | 1700 | 1500 |
| 123960 | 31-Mar-2022 | 2100 | 1700 |
| 123960 | 30-Apr-2022 | 1900 | 2100 |

Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the [LAG](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions070.htm) function to do that, example:

```
create table acounts (
account_no number,
month_end_date DATE, balance number);


insert into acounts values(123960,  '31-Dec-2021',  1000)
insert into acounts values(123960,  '31-Jan-2022',  1500);
insert into acounts values(123960,  '28-Feb-2022',  1700);



sELECT 
    account_no,
    month_end_date, 
    balance,
    LAG(balance) OVER (
        ORDER BY month_end_date
    ) py_sales
FROM 
    acounts
    where account_no = 123960
```

Answer (score 1):

This quer is for multiple accounts and would summ fi9rst, the balance for every month and year for every acount

> ```
> WITH CTE AS 
> (
> sELECT 
>     account_no,
>     MIN(month_end_date) month_end_date,
>     to_char(month_end_date, 'YYYY-MM') monthyear,
>     SUM(balance) balance
> FROM acounts
> GROUP BY     account_no,to_char(month_end_date, 'YYYY-MM')
> )
> sELECT 
>     account_no,
>     month_end_date, 
>     balance,
>     NVL(LAG(balance) OVER (
>     PARTITION BY account_no
>         ORDER BY monthyear
>     ),0) prior_sales
> FROM 
>     CTE
> ```

> ```
> ACCOUNT_NO | MONTH_END_DATE | BALANCE | PRIOR_SALES
> ---------: | :------------- | ------: | ----------:
>     123960 | 31-DEC-21      |    1000 |           0
>     123960 | 31-JAN-22      |    1500 |        1000
>     123960 | 28-FEB-22      |    1700 |        1500
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=6133f0c4b70d1e64fde093bf9085aec2)*